# Widgets inside dojo dgrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dgrid

Our company moved from `dojox/DataGrid` to `dgrid` some time back. Now we are finding out, [dgrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/) doesn't seem to support dijit/dojox widgets out of the box.

`dojox/DataGrid` has a `formatter()` that can return a widget. So easy to doo it there! The [API comparison on GitHub](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/API-Comparison) says

> "dgrid supports formatter functions, but doesn't support returning a
>   widget from them .dgrid also has renderCell, which is expected to
>   return a DOM node. This could ostensibly be used for displaying
>   widgets (and the editor column plugin does exactly this). Note that
>   for cell editing purposes, use of the editor column plugin is highly
>   encouraged."

**How exactly?**

I have tried using the editor plugin with `{editor: ' ', editorArgs:' '}`. This does render a widget but is too restrictive. Eg How do I render a `dijit/Button` with its label being the value of the cell? Or something more complex, how do I use a (lesser known) `dojox/image/MagnifierLite` with an `<img>` generated from a formatter function with the `src` being the value of the store?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use this sample code

```
require(
    [
        "dgrid/List",
        "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
        "dgrid/Selection",
        "dgrid/editor",
        "dgrid/Keyboard",
        "dgrid/tree",
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/store/JsonRest",
        "dojo/store/Observable",
        "dojo/store/Cache",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ],

    function(
        List, 
        Grid, 
        Selection, 
        editor, 
        Keyboard, 
        tree, 
        declare, 
        JsonRest, 
        Observable, 
        Cache, 
        Memory, 
        Button
    ) {

        var columns = [
            {
                label:"Actions", 
                field:"id", 
                width: "200px", 
                renderCell: actionRenderCell
            }
        ];

        var actionRenderCell = function (object, data, cell) {

            var btnDelete = new Button({
                rowId : object.id,
                label: "Delete",
                onClick: function () {
                    myStore.remove(this.rowId);
                }
            }, cell.appendChild(document.createElement("div")));

            btnDelete._destroyOnRemove = true;

            return btnDelete;

        }

        grid = new (declare([Grid, Selection, Keyboard]))({
            store: myStore,
            getBeforePut: false,
            columns: columns
        }, "grid");

}
```

Comment: Yes! That works! Thanks! In your example you are effectively using renderCell like formatter in dojox/DataGrid.

The documentation for dgrid states that if formatter and renderCell both are applied, formatter is ignored. 

Any idea why it is designed so?

Comment: This code does work but I am fairly certain that it has a memory leak.  [To avoid this use removeRow](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.15/doc/usage/Working-with-Widgets.md#destroying-rendered-widgets)