# Widgets inside Dojo dgrid OnDemandList

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I'm trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444162/widgets-inside-dojo-dgrid) but using an OnDemandList instead of an OnDemandGrid.

Here is what I have so far

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dgrid/OnDemandList",
    "widget/CategoryItem",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/text!./templates/category-list.html"
], function(declare, _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, OnDemandList, CategoryItem, domConstruct, template) {
    var CatList = declare([OnDemandList]);
    return declare([_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        baseClass: "category-list",

        postCreate: function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);

            // Create OnDemandList, place in div defined in template.
            var cat1 = this.cat1 = new CatList({
                store: this.store,
                renderRow: this.renderItem
            }, this.categoriesLevel0);

        },

        renderItem: function(item) {
            return new CategoryItem({
                title: item.title
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is my renderItems function needs to somehow return a dom containing my custom widget. As it is now I get this error `Error on domReady callback: Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it definitely needs to return a dom node from renderRow. Assuming you're using _WidgetBase for CategoryItem it should work like:

```
renderItem: function(item) {
    var category = new CategoryItem({
        title: item.title
    });
    return category.domNode;
}
```

The example here: https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid does pretty much the same thing, except it uses put-selector, which is just constructing a div, attaching the widget to it and returning the new div.

Comment: Obvious question here is, is the CategoryItem widget you create ever destroyed?  You return the DOM node which may be cleaned up by dgrid destroying the row, but normally the Javascript object that is the dijit instance is only destroyed by calling destroy() on it.  Update: found the answer to my own question: https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/doc/usage/Working-with-Widgets.md - essentially, hook onto 'removeRow' on the dgrid, and call destroyRecursive on the cellElement.widget.  The simple approach shown above contains a dangerous memory leak.